# Loading a Japanese web page with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, encoding, html-agility-pack

I have this piece of code to load and parse web pages using `HtmlAgilityPack`. It works for most web pages, but wen I tried to load a Japanese web page, it seems the encoding is wrong. How can I do this? Actually how can I set encoding based on web page encoding?

```
class Program {

    private const string HttpMethod = "GET";

    private const string UserAgent =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41 Safari/534.7";

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://infoseek.co.jp/") as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request == null)
            return;
        request.Method = HttpMethod;
        request.UserAgent = UserAgent;
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response == null)
            return;
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var document = new HtmlDocument {
            OptionCheckSyntax = true,
            OptionFixNestedTags = true,
            OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true,
            OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            OptionReadEncoding = true
        };
        document.Load(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        var d = document.DocumentNode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get encoding from HttpWebResponse object by code below. Do you see any problem or have you any other idea?

```
class Program {

    private const string HttpMethod = "GET";

    private const string UserAgent =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41 Safari/534.7";

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://infoseek.co.jp/") as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request == null)
            return;
        request.Method = HttpMethod;
        request.UserAgent = UserAgent;
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response == null)
            return;
        var encoding = TryGetEncoding(response);
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var document = new HtmlDocument {
            OptionCheckSyntax = true,
            OptionFixNestedTags = true,
            OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true,
            OptionReadEncoding = true,
            OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = encoding
        };
        document.Load(stream, encoding);
        var d = document.DocumentNode;
    }

    private static Encoding TryGetEncoding(HttpWebResponse response) {
        var charset = response.CharacterSet;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(charset))
            charset = response.ContentEncoding;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(charset))
            return Encoding.UTF8;
        try {
            return Encoding.GetEncoding(charset);
        } catch {
            return Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

infoseek.co.jp responds with the HTTP header

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=EUC-JP
```

which is mirrored in the HTML tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-JP">
```

In .Net, use [Code Page 51932](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) to decode EUC-JP.

Comment: Yes I know. But the problem is this tag is accessible after document loaded, but encoding is required while document is loading. Have you any idea please?

Comment: have a look at the last answer in this thread http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/60174 . It uses System.Net.WebClient to retrieve the page as string, and then passes the string to create an HtmlDocument